# How can I quantify over the class of all cardinalities?

Tags: logic, category-theory, cardinals, abstract-algebra

I'd like to quantify over all cardinalities of sets.

My end goal is to make a category-theoretic arguement:

For all cardinalities of sets, in the category of sets with maps as morphisms: the subclass of objects with that given cardinality is closed under the class of isomorphisms, thereby forming a subcategory, for each set cardinality, where the morphisms are isomorphisms.

Can I quantify over a class that isn't a set?

Is there a good way to specify this class of cardinalities?

Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: Why do you need to talk of cardinalities at all? For any given set, you are looking at sets in bijection to it. No need to talk of proper classes of the equivalence relation of equipotency, or of introducing ordinals to talk of cardinals as initial ordinals.

Comment: You *can* quantify over a class $C$ that isn't a set. What you can't do is form the powerset $2^C$, the singleton $\{C\}$ etc.

Answer (score 5):

In $\sf ZFC$ classes are really just a shorthand for formulas. That is when we say that $a\in A$ we really say that some $\varphi(x)$ is a formula in the language of set theory and $\sf ZFC\vdash\varphi(a)$.

So to quantify over a class $A$ we really just have a formula $\varphi$ and we say that $\forall x(\varphi(x)\rightarrow\ldots)$, or in simpler terms $\forall x\in A(\ldots)$.

Similarly the cardinals are a well-defined class in $\sf ZFC$. It is the class of ordinals which do not have an injection into a smaller ordinal; but since smaller ordinals are elements of larger ordinals, it means that we can say that there is no injection from $x$ into any of its elements.

In $\sf ZF$ the definition is slightly longer and more complicated, but we can do that as well. You just have to write the definition of a cardinal, which is longer, and then you take the class of all those satisfying this definition.

---

I suddenly realized a possible source for confusion. When we say "quantify over something" we have two meanings, which are almost always clear from context:

1. That something is the object which is being quantified. For example "Quantify over $x$", meaning that $\forall x\varphi(x)$ and so on.
2. That something is the collection of objects which we are interested in. For example, "Quantify over all the real numbers" - $\forall x\in\Bbb R$

Classes are not objects, in $\sf ZFC$ anyway, so we cannot quantify over them in the first sense, but in the second sense we can, because of what I wrote above. Quantifying over all the cardinals is in the second sense of the term, rather than the first.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to prove something like
$$\forall x \forall y(x \cong y \to |x| = |y|)$$
This is possible without quantifying over all cardinals (and, depending on your definition of cardinality, is a somewhat trivial result).

The fact that the class of sets of a given cardinality is closed under isomorphisms (bijections) is immediate: if $\kappa$ is a cardinal then, given any set $x$ of cardinality $\kappa$, if $y$ is another set and $x \cong y$ then $y$ also has cardinality $\kappa$, so lies in the class. (This is a very verbose rewording of the above expression though.)