# How do I quantify over the proper class of all the cardinal numbers?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, quantifiers

I want to make a statement like this:

$\forall x\forall y\in S, (x>y) \lor (x=y) \lor (x<y)$

Where S is the set of all cardinalities. The problem is that such a set doesn't exist and to describe all cardinalities one needs to use a proper class.

I want to know how I can frame the above statement, which is essentially that the cardinal numbers obey the law of trichotomy, without having to refer to bijections in place of cardinal numbers. I want to treat the cardinal numbers as their own objects.

Comment: What set theory are you using?

Comment: A cardinal number is definable within $ZFC$ (an ordinal number with certain properties). To quantify over cardinal numbers you just have to say "for all $x$, if $x$ has such and such properties (i.e. is a cardinal) then $P$"

Comment: When I said there is no set of all cardinalities I was referring to this post: [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/512658/how-can-i-quantify-over-the-class-of-all-cardinalities)

Comment: It is true that there is no set of all cardinalities, but there is no need for set for this statement: $\forall x\forall y((C(x)\land C(y))\rightarrow ((x>y) \lor (x=y) \lor (x<y)))$ where $C(x)$ is the statement $x$ is a cardinal

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, remember that bounded quantifies don't really exist. It's a shorthand, $\forall x\in S, \varphi$ is really $\forall x(x\in S\rightarrow \varphi)$.

Now combine this with the fact that since classes are not objects, writing $x\in S$, when $S$ is a proper class, is just a shorthand for $\psi(x)$, where $\psi$ is the formula defining $S$.

And from here you are all done.

Comment: To the proposer: For example $x\in ON$ is short for "Every member of $x# is a subset of $x,$  and  $x$ is well-oredered by $\in.$"

Comment: Didn't know bounded quantifiers we're just a shorthand. I guess that means every quantifier needs some implied domain of discourse which is meta to the statement itself. Very interesting!

Comment: No, quantifiers quantify over *everything*. All sets. Bounded quantifiers are shorthands to make it clearer that we are only interested in a particular set. But you can bound them to a class just as easily.